# Why the template in this AngularJS ui-router sample not displaying in the browser?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the link to the sample AngularJS ui-router application: http://plnkr.co/edit/UJGakX?p=preview, `which was written/posted by someone on this site.`

You can see that everything is working fine in there--the template home.html is displaying on the right side.  There are no errors in the code.

I downloaded and saved this application to a folder on my computer.  However, when I open index.html in a browser from this folder, the template is not displaying in the browser.  I tried a few other ui-router apps, and their templates were not displaying either. I use Chrome and Firefox.  Am I missing something? I'm fairly new to Angular and currently building a personal website using Angular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On a local file system you can't actually do ajax. If you see your index file URL as something like this file:///users/desktop/index.html  You will not be allowed to request the home.html page Instead you need to setup a local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening the index.html directly as an file. Thus, it will load with either `file://` or `C:/`, and not `http://` 
ui-router requires an webserver to work. Your browser is requesting the URL to load ui-router from the web server, not from angularJS. 
 
So you can either install a webserver such as wamp/xampp in your local PC and open this project through it. It'll work as you expected.